An 8-bit integer is a ring. What do eight qubits form?
I don't know if this question is well-posed, but I'm looking at computational proofs with classical fixed-width integers. The ones I'm looking at write proofs using rings (the algebraic structure), then state e.g. an 8-bit natural number (along with appropriate operations) is a ring.
I want to know if there's a quantum analogue for this, and what structure you'd use in place of a ring for qubits.
Perhaps the difficulty in asking this question is that I can't say what the quantum analogue of an 8-bit nat is, or if there is one.
Background
An 8-bit natural number as a ring
Here's my understanding of an 8-bit integer as a ring. Bear in mind I've only read about rings today. Referencing the definition of ring on Wikipedia. The ring R is {0, 1, 2, ..., 255} along with modulo addition (with neutral 0) and multiplication (neutral 1).
You can derive proofs about rings in abstract. For example, that a * neutral = neutral given multiplication is distributive over addition, and the neutral value axioms. Then you declare that an 8-bit integer (in Idris Bits8 with (+) and (-)), is a ring, by writing the axioms in terms of Bits8.
p.s. I looked through all the tags and couldn't find an appropriate one. programming seemed closest

Not sure I know how to answer, but I think of $SU(2^n)$ as the unitary group describing transformations of pure states of $n$ qubits

Your question is a bit strange if not incorrect. What do you mean by a ring? If by the ring you mean the algebraic structure then a "8-bit  natural number is a ring" is an incorrect statement. I suggest to clarify the question and give a proper context or definitions of the terms you use.

@MonteNero I've update the question, let me know if it needs more changes. I'm thinking of this

I think @MonteNero knows what modular arithmetic is, you still haven't explained what makes an 8-bit natural number a ring. You mean: computational proofs consider modular arithmetic using 8-bit numbers? The numbers still are not rings.
Anyway, you probably want the Lie group

yes yes I realise. I'm not doubting anyone's intelligence here. I'm referring to this project

I still don't understand your question, but qubits' states are vectors that live in the vector space $\mathbb{C^{2^n}}$. Rings have nothing to do with qubits unless you are after something very specific.

The question sounds interesting but people aren’t connecting it yet. Perhaps if you gave an example of how a classical 8-bit register is used as a ring in a computational proof.
